# Most efficient way to turn a list of strings of integers to an array of integers

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I've got a simple problem - I need to convert a string of integers to a list of integers and insert it into a numpy array.

I have code that works but I'm interested in a more efficient method if there is one. The starting condition is that I have a list of strings of integers (line 4) and the goal is to get a numpy array filled with those integers.

Here is an example of the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
print("Hello StackOverflow")

listOfStringOfINTs = ["123231231231231"]*5
print(listOfStringOfINTs)
numpyVectorOfInts = np.empty([len(listOfStringOfINTs),len(listOfStringOfINTs[0]) ], dtype='int')
for i, IntString in enumerate(listOfStringOfINTs):
    numpyVectorOfInts[i] = list(map(int, IntString))

print(numpyVectorOfInts)
```

Comment: Camel case for variables names is not a good practice in Python. Use "snake_case" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try to adhere to it in the future.

Comment: Do they have same number of characters in each string?

Comment: Camel case is not "bad" practice.  Snake case is just the preferred convention in Python.  I prefer camel, so I use that and have no problem reading functions and variable names.

Comment: @Divakar yeah, all have same number of characters. I get them from a binary file (optimally I would save and load something different than a string of list of ints to the binary file, but that's all I could figure out in my time limits)

Comment: @artembus Added a vectorized solution to use that scenario.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Hi @Divakar, sorry for the delay, was in a conference. Yeah I tried the solutions and yours is really elegant. I'm yet to test all of the solutions in my program, as soon as I will compare the performance I'll add an update and select the best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is better in speed, but it's simpler:

```
In [68]: np.array([list(astr) for astr in listOfStringOfINTs],int)           
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]])
```

`list(astr)` split the string into a list of 1 character strings.  The `np.array` with `int` dtype takes care of converting all strings.

Or you could join all strings into string, make the list, and then reshape the array:

```
np.array(list(''.join(listOfStringOfINTs)),int).reshape(5,-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Leveraging the fact that all strings have the same number of characters, we can use a vectorized one with `view` -

```
def get_int_ar(a):
    return (np.array(a).view('u1')-48).reshape(len(a),-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: listOfStringOfINTs = ["123231231231231"]*5

In [144]: get_int_ar(listOfStringOfINTs)
Out[144]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is another way to do it:

```
>>> np.vstack(np.frombuffer(a,dtype=np.uint8)-48 for a in listOfStringOfINTs)
array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

This method relies on reading in the ASCII characters as unsigned chars and then relying on the fact that the numerals 1-9 are in order in the ASCII representation. Since the numeral 0 is represented as 48, we just subtract 48 from all of the values to get their value as an integer.

For small strings it's not really faster than @hpaulj's method which is more readable:

```
In [1]: listOfStringOfINTs = ["123231231231231"]*10000

In [2]: %timeit np.vstack(np.frombuffer(a,dtype=np.uint8)-48 for a in listOfStringOfINTs)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.array([list(astr) for astr in listOfStringOfINTs],int)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.3 ms per loop
```

But for large strings it can make a big difference:

```
In [4]: listOfStringOfINTs = ["123231231231231"*1000]*10000

In [5]: %timeit np.vstack(np.frombuffer(a,dtype=np.uint8)-48 for a in listOfStringOfINTs)
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit np.array([list(astr) for astr in listOfStringOfINTs],int)
1 loop, best of 3: 30.4 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are correct, but intuitively, the easiest to understand for me is:

```
    >>> k = [list(x) for x in listOfStringOfINTs ]
    >>> print(np.array(k, dtype=np.int64))
    [[1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1]
     [1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1]
     [1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1]
     [1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1]
     [1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a soln using `"".join`:

```
def digit_ize(a):
    r = np.fromstring(''.join(a), 'u1')
    r &= 0x0f
    return r.reshape(len(a), -1)
```

or (slightly faster):

```
def digit_ize(a):
    r = np.frombuffer(''.join(a).encode(), 'u1') & 0x0f
    return r.reshape(len(a), -1)
```

Timings:

```
small
pp1 4.314555088058114
pp2 2.933372976258397
div 3.740947926416993
usr 29.473979957401752
hpj 12.974489014595747
large
pp1 9.718517074361444
pp2 7.069707033224404
div 37.66830707900226
usr 2321.8201039126143
hpj 1103.1720889732242
```

Script to produce timings, contains Py3 adjustments of other solns where necessary.

```
import numpy as np

def digit_ize():
    r = np.fromstring(''.join(a), 'u1')
    r &= 0x0f
    return r.reshape(len(a), -1)

def digit_ize_2():
    r = np.frombuffer(''.join(a).encode(), 'u1') & 0x0f
    return r.reshape(len(a), -1)

def get_int_ar():
    return (np.array(a, 'S').view('u1')-48).reshape(len(a),-1)

def use_vstack():
    np.vstack(np.frombuffer(b.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)-48 for b in a)

def use_list():
    return np.array([list(astr) for astr in a],int)           

from timeit import timeit

listOfStringOfINTs = ["123231231231231"]*5
a = listOfStringOfINTs
print("small")
print("pp1", timeit(digit_ize, number=1000)*1000)
print("pp2", timeit(digit_ize_2, number=1000)*1000)
print("div", timeit(get_int_ar, number=1000)*1000)
print("usr", timeit(use_vstack, number=1000)*1000)
print("hpj", timeit(use_list, number=1000)*1000)
a = a*100
print("large")
print("pp1", timeit(digit_ize, number=1000)*1000)
print("pp2", timeit(digit_ize_2, number=1000)*1000)
print("div", timeit(get_int_ar, number=1000)*1000)
print("usr", timeit(use_vstack, number=1000)*1000)
print("hpj", timeit(use_list, number=1000)*1000)
```